# HTACCESS apart from specified directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, directory

I currently have a `RewriteRule` setup so that anything after the domain gets passed as a variable to pages.php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ pages.php?alias=$1
```

So for example, `http://www.example.com/contactus` shows the content from `http://www.example.com/pages.php?alias=contactus` this is working fine.

Is it possible to continue with the above but exclude a specific directory, which should act 'normally'.

So, `http://www.example.com/shop` actually goes to `http://www.example.com/shop` and doesn't get redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it so the rule won't get applied to *any* existing file or directory, you'd want:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ pages.php?alias=$1
```

If you want it so the rule *only* ignores the `shop` directory, then:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/shop
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ pages.php?alias=$1
```